# Does salesforce development benefit from having a hyperthreaded cpu?

Tags: ide, developer-productivity

This isnt a development question but more of asking how salesforce utilizes local resources and what the best system is for development

Reason being is because im building a new pc and cant decide on whether going for an i5 or i7. I have been researching for a while now and found out that an ide like visual studio and android development benefit a lot from hyperthreading because they are both optimized for multithreading.

How about salesforce; does salesforce development benefit from a hyperthreaded cpu? Does st/mavensmate utilize this when compiling? Is the developer console optimized for multithreading?

Or it absolutely doesnt matter because saleforce is all about the cloud so having a faster internet would be better than an i7?

Comment: Depends a bit one what sort of development you are doing. The heavy lifting is done in Apex, which is done in the cloud. So your local setup will do nothing to help with that. However, Javascript runs in your browser, so anything that lets your browser run faster/better will assist with that. I suspect the developer console utilizes JS (you can check for yourself). However, for the most part, I would say a good internet connection is more important than a hyperthreaded cpu. That said, not an expert.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Did some research and found that JS runs in a singlethread and will not benefit from hyperthreading. That said looks like better connection and higher memory would be best

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compilation occurs on the server, not the client, so the biggest limiting factor is bandwidth, and that's not a very big requirement in general cases. If you choose to use the browser console for development (the Developer Console), having beefier hardware will reduce loading time and increase responsiveness, but that's still generally a single-threaded job, so hyper threading is of little use here either. For any IDE, having faster cores with more memory will serve you better than hyper threading.